# Negating string comparison in `if` confusing

Tags: python

The output of this confuses me! when the output of == are N and M, Shouldn't the output of != be A and I?. Word entered is "Nima".

```
word = input("Enter a word:")
UpperWord= word.upper()

for letter in word:
    
    if letter == "A":
        continue
    elif letter == "E":
        continue
    elif letter == "I":
        continue
    elif letter == "O":
        continue
    elif letter == "U":
        continue
    else:
        print(letter)
```

---

```
word = input("Enter a word:")
UpperWord= word.upper()

for letter in word:
    
    if letter != "A":
        continue
    elif letter != "E":
        continue
    elif letter != "I":
        continue
    elif letter != "O":
        continue
    elif letter != "U":
        continue
    else:
        print(letter)
```

Comment: Please do NOT ask a question in the title. And you never used `UpperWord`.

Comment: @DYZ Why not ask a question in the title? Isn't that what the title is for? Did you mean "do not put the entire body of the question in the title"?

Comment: `continue` takes you to the top of the  loop. For every character except "A", the first if's `continue` short circuits the comparison. if you happen to have "A", its not "E" so once again you jump out of the if and go to the top of the loop.

Comment: You're saving the uppercase word in `UpperWord`, then not using it.  Change your `for` loops to `for letter in UpperWord:`

Comment: It's not specifically your question, but you could replace all of those if/elif statements with `if letter in "AEIOU":` or `if letter not in "AEIOU":`

Comment: The title is a bit wordy, but why the close votes? We've got running programs that demonstrate the problem and a statement of what is wanted.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, that's what I meant, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The condition `if letter != "A"` is true for all letters but 'A', and for all of them, you execute `continue` and skip to the next iteration of the loop. The `elif letter != "E"` statement is executed only when the letter is 'A'. Since the letter is already known to be 'A', the condition is always true and the second `continue` statement is always executed. The second code fragment never produces any output.

Here's what you want:

```
for letter in UpperWord:    
    if letter not in "AEUIO":
        continue
    print(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

As [DYZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62616356/6657931) says, the second code fragment would never produce output, because it actually continues the loop for all letters.

Remember, thee code executes from top to bottom, so to avoid this issue, check all of the vowels at once.

You also initialize `UpperWord`, but never use it, so unless the character is uppercase, it will always fall through.
 Here is the combination of both fixes:

```
vowelString = "AEIOU"
word = input("Enter a word:")
upperWord= word.upper()
for letter in upperWord:
    if letter not in vowelString:
        print(letter)
```

If you're up for it, I would also recommend researching Regular Expressions, or RegEx. This is a pattern-matching system that would make it much easier to match things going forward.

The solution with regex would look like:

```
import re
vowelRegex = re.compile(r"[aeiouAEIOU]")
word = input("Enter a word:")
for letter in word:
    if vowelRegex.match(letter)==None:
        print(letter)
```

This would easily allow you to expand your searched characters, as well as expanding to searching for more complex patterns.

[Python Regex Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)
[Regex Playground](https://regexr.com/)